# Repeating PartialView in 'collapsable' Table Row

Tags: html, html-table, partial-views

I have an HTML table that present some data to the user. For each row there is an associated log file that can be viewed. At present this is shown using the same, single partial view, and as such it always appears below the table. In the example below this is fine, as with only 3 rows you can see it.

[image: Current view mockup - log is always below the table]

In practise there will be many rows (50+) and so I don't want people to be scrolling up and down the page, nor forgetting which log they are viewing.

To address both these issues I was thinking that it would be nice to have the log for a given row appear below that row, with the 'Show File' changing to a 'Hide File'. And when hidden for there to be no space taken up/allocated to the log partial view.

But how do I achieve this? How do I have a table that has multiple columns in one row, and one column in another (I realise I can't, but how do I get that effect - only fill column one and let it overflow for the log partial view)

Or is there a better/more standard way of presenting this information that doesn't use tables?

[image: Desired look with a partial view for each row]